# int main (int ac, char **av)

Tags: c, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does int argc, char *argv[] mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean)

```
int main (int ac, char **av)
{
  /* functions*/
}
```

What are meant by ac and av here?

Comment: FYI: Traditionally, these parameters are called `argc` and `argv`.

Answer (score 9):

**ac** is **argument count.

**av** should be `char **av` and it's an array of string pointers containing command line arguments.

So, if you invoke your program like this:

```
$ ./prog 1 2 3
```

**ac** will have a value of 4 and **av** will be something like:

```
av[0] -> "prog"
av[1] -> "1"
av[2] -> "2"
av[3] -> "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

`ac` is a number of parameters passed to the program.

`char **` av is an array of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

attribute count and attribute value

Comment: should it be `argument`?